# @ResponseStatus, the client does not receive an error message

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, response

I have code with a custom exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Login is busy")
    public class LoginIsBusyException extends RuntimeException{
}
```

And a method that can throw it:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST) 
public void registration(@RequestBody UserRest user) throws 
LoginIsBusyException{
  userService.checkAlreadyExist(user.getLogin(), user.getMail());
  user.setActive(false);
  UserRest userRest = userService.addUser(user);
  Integer randomToken = randomTokenService.getRandomToken(userRest.getMail());
  mailService.sendMail(randomToken, userRest.getLogin(), userRest.getMail());
}
```

The problem is that the client receives only the error code but does not receive the statusText *"Login is busy"*, Already tried to add a method catching this exception

```
@ExceptionHandler(LoginIsBusyException.class)
public void handleException(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException 
{
   response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Login is busy");
}
```

But, the message is lost somewhere and the customer gets this response: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed `@ResponseBody` for your `handleException` method and also it **returns `void`** with your current code i.e., you are NOT passing the `response` body, as shown below:

```
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(LoginIsBusyException.class)
public String handleException(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException 
{
   response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Login is busy");
}
```

or else you use `ResponseEntity` to produce both header and body as shown below

```
@ExceptionHandler(LoginIsBusyException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> 
                handleException(LoginIsBusyException exe) {
   return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Login is busy");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. But i didn't use `@ResponseBody` because I used `@RestController` annotation. I decided this question differently. More precisely, I was wrong waiting for the message to be in the header. Message was in json body. I understood this when got response in SoapUi. Custom exception works correctly, that was my mistake. Your answer is correctly too.